# Can I see the history of key presses in normal mode?

Tags: command-history, normal-mode

I know that Vim keeps history for ex commands, searches, jump locations, changes, and possibly others.

With `showcmd` set, Vim also shows you what keys you have entered so far for a normal mode command, until that command is executed.

Sometimes, when in normal mode, I mistype and actions occur. I can undo these actions, but I sometimes want to know how the edits during my blunder occurred. Sometimes the edit looks cool and I want to know how to repeat it in the future.

So, is there any way of seeing the history of key presses in normal mode, preferably delimited when an actual edit or action (like movement or mode change) occurred?

Comment: Possibly related: http://www.drbunsen.org/vim-croquet/

Answer (score 23):

Following the link from @WChargin a bit further, I found this:

You can start vim with the [`-w`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-w) or [`-W`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-W) option as follows:

```
vim -w keys.txt my_file
```

> All the characters that you type are recorded in the file {scriptout}, until you exit Vim.

`-w` will append to the specified file if it exists; `-W` will overwrite it.

It doesn't quite get you what you want, but it's the right direction.

*Update:* It looks like vim actually buffers all the keystrokes until you quit vim, but there is a one-line patch [here](https://gist.github.com/kana/4202311) that will write the keystrokes immediately.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using this as a starting point for poking into the source code. It looks like -w saves every single key press, not just normal-mode commands, but you are correct: it is the right direction!

Comment: @xthrd, how are these `keys.txt` file formatted/structured? When I use `-w`, appending is always happening in a long-long-long line; and, there are weird characters displayed: under UTF-8, whenever I open a file in a new buffer, I will get `€齛`. This is a good marker by itself, but it would be great if the logs could be parsed optionally.

Comment: @llinfeng It's not formatted at all. It's literally just a file containing the keystrokes in the order they were made. (Although note that if some of the keystrokes are `<cr>`, then the file will contain linebreaks.) This is because the main purpose is for creating files that can be played back with the `-s` option. But why not try it out for yourself!

Comment: @Rich Thank you for clarifying. I have used this key-tracking mechanism to debug the problem that started my search. [My lesson is that: never map `W` for the command line.]

Comment: @llinfeng Why not?

Comment: @Aaron Frankly speaking, I don't remember why I said that. 

Though, with `command! W some_other_thing` in my `.vimrc`, the logging with `-W` still works as intended. That is, the logging method should still work with `:W` mapped to do something else.

Per my "old lesson about `W`", well, I may have been referring to something that started my search back in 2017.

Answer (score -4):

There is `q:` which shows a command history.

I also find it useful that you can press up  in a partially completed command to cycle through matches.  E.g. 

`/abc`

Then pressing up will cycle through your history of searches starting with 'abc'

Comment: q: shows ex command history, and is useful, but is not a log of normal commands, like "ad2tn (delete into register a until the second n)

Comment: Don't forget that while in the middle of editing a command you can bring up current line in the history editor and use vi to edit the line by pressing `Ctrl+f`