# Showing command history with showcmd

Tags: options, command-history

When using `set showcmd` Vim shows partial commands in the last line of the screen. For example, in Normal mode when typing the command `dt.` the last line shows `dt` and then, when you hit `.` the command is complete and therefore nothing is shown.

Is there a way to show full commands? For example when typing `dt.gU(`, first `dt.` would be shown; and when starting to type the second command the first would be cleared, so that in the end only `gU(` would is displayed.

This could be useful for example in illustrating GIFs; and to check that you typed what you wanted if you face some unexpected result.

Comment: What is a full command? The `dt` is shown because it's the current operator pending. Once it's given a motion, it's no longer an operator pending. Suppose we went further, and did `dt.gU(gu)daw` or so. Is all of that "one full command", or is it four full commands, or something else?

Comment: @mixedmath for me that would count as 4 commands. The second paragraph of the answer tries to disambiguate what I mean.

Comment: From Vim's perspective, `dt.gU(` are 2 commands: `dt.`  and `gU(`.... So what you really want is show some sort of command history (Vim is already showing the "full comamnds").

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, yeah, that might be what I want. Thank you for editing the question title.

Comment: I've been poking in the Vim source code working on the [normal history](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/570/can-i-see-the-history-of-key-presses-in-normal-mode). In `src/normal.c` the code calls `clear_showcmd()` in several places (`normal_cmd()`, `do_pending_operator()`, `end_visual_mode()`). I'm playing with dumping to a file the `showcmd_buf` at those points, which was looking pretty good, but makes me pretty sure that you can't get what you want without similarly modifying the Vim source code and rebuilding it. Of course, doing so might be worth the hassle to make your gifs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the trouble, @JohnO'M. If you arrive to a conclusion make sure to post it as an answer. I searched the web (quite) a bit for this kind of feature and found nothing.

Comment: Related: [Vim plugin that explains commands as you type them](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7326/vim-plugin-that-explains-commands-as-you-type-them) at softwarerecs SE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to do this in a regular Vim. However, if you are willing to patch Vim, the following may work for you.

The very simple patch (applied against Vim-7.4.052) disables the actual update to the screen that clears the history at the end of a normal command. It does this by returning whether or not `showcmd_is_clear` is set prior to updating the display,. (alternatively, you can comment out the if statement and leave just the one original `return` line. **note**: The patch below didn't paste very well; you may have to apply this by hand, though it is just a short one-liner. **note**: I did *not* comment out the actual `display_showcmd()` because it appears to be used in visual mode to update the display of the number of selected lines or other possibly other stuff. I have not extensively tested this.

```
--- src/normal.c    2015-02-14 00:21:23.286352257 -0500
+++ src/normal.c    2015-02-14 00:21:25.238352173 -0500
@@ -4029,6 +4029,7 @@
    /* Don't actually display something if there is nothing to clear. */
    if (showcmd_is_clear)
        return;
+   return;
     }

     display_showcmd()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Screencast showing the patch]

A few interesting things to note:

- This shows even simple movements, like `j`, `k`, `b`, etc.
- The `x` command actually becomes `dl` in the showcmd_buf.
- Commands that change the bottom line obliterate the showcmd area (for example, using the `:` command, or entering insert mode (at least in my setup))
- The capture program stopped recording many strokes after I typed a `"`, but my key sequence is visible in the vim window for my long register specified yank.
- Not shown in the cast, but hitting <kbd>esc</kbd> in normal mode shows `^[` in the showcmd area

Answer (score 5):

Apart of [John](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/786/467) solution, there is another way to show all vim keystrokes which were pressed by using `-w` parameter which record all the characters that you type in the file. The problem is, that vim writes keystrokes only when you exit Vim. This is how [VimGolf](http://www.vimgolf.com/) works.

To workaround this, [Kana Natsuno](https://github.com/kana) came up with this [single-line patch](https://gist.github.com/kana/4202311), which disables buffering of the `-w` option, so you have access to realtime stream of keystrokes. Then it's a matter of reading them (e.g. `tail -f`), parsing or you can try to display them in the statusbar (`:set statusline`).

Check out a custom build of Vim using Drew's [live-stream-keystrokes branch](https://github.com/nelstrom/macvim/commit/c65e7e650b806682152681c58078d29cb1904bfe) of MacVim, to get the realtime stream of keystrokes.

Source: [Vimprint - a Vim keystroke parser](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/05/vimprint---a-vim-keystroke-parser/) at Drew Neil blog

This is useful if you'd like to reveal the Vim pressed keystrokes in video tutorials or GIFs.

Comment: upvote just for the vimgolf link :)