# How to display invoked keystrokes and commands in normal mode?

Tags: command-history, options, normal-mode

How I can activate option which will display my pressed keystrokes or executed commands in normal mode on the screen?

Especially it would be good, if it would give a slight info what specific keystroke did (like in case of errors).

I've tried to use `:set showcmd`, but it doesn't show single keystrokes like `w`, `b`, `j`, etc.

I know it's possible to [show a command history](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/570/can-i-see-the-history-of-key-presses-in-normal-mode) by `q:`, but I'm looking for some method of displaying them automatically on the screen while using/pressing them.

Comment: Related: [Showing command history with showcmd](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/742/showing-command-history-with-showcmd), but I wouldn't like to modify the vim sources.

Comment: This is just the same question? There is one answer, which states that it's not possible without editing the source; perhaps more answers are possible (doubt it)

Comment: I've tried to use `:set showcmd`, but it doesn't show keystrokes like `w`, `b`, `j`, etc.

Comment: Related: [Vim plugin that explains commands as you type them](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7326/vim-plugin-that-explains-commands-as-you-type-them) at softwarerecs SE

Comment: It looks like the same question as [Showing command history with showcmd](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/742/showing-command-history-with-showcmd), the title wasn't so obvious, however editing vim sources doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: No, but (what you consider to be) a bad answer is not a reason to ask the same question again just a few days later :-) Maybe if the other question was a 5-year old outdated question, but that's obviously not the case...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Most of the original questions usually have very low quality question titles, so it's almost impossible to find the right answer which you're looking for. I hope this duplicate will find locating the right question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly related: [Can I see the history of key presses in normal mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/570/can-i-see-the-history-of-key-presses-in-normal-mode)

That question is about displaying the history of the commands in normal mode. If you are asking about the ex command history, then do

`q:`

Comment: Thanks, but you've to check the command history every time manually, but I'm looking for some method of displaying them on the screen automatically.