# Cycle through edit command history

Tags: command-history, repeated-commands

In Vim, i can cycle through edit locations with `g,` and `g;`, and jump  to locations with `Ctrl-I` and `Ctrl-O`. Is there any way to similarly cycle through edit commands? This would be something similar to `Ctrl-R` command available in the shell.

In other words - a period command `.` lets me execute the last edit repeatedly, but what if I wanted to execute the one before last, or second before last? Is this functionality available?

Thanks!

Comment: No, Vim doesn't keep a history of normal mode commands.

Comment: Oh well. Could be possible with a plugin perhaps.

Comment: @siphiuel No, Vim doesn't keep a history; a plugin is just a bunch of Vim commands, so it can't change that. This question has come up in some form or the other a number of times, such as [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/742/51) and [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/570/51) (I've closed this as a duplicate as this is effectively the same question; showing the history is a pre-requisite for cycling through it).