# Use backspace to modify the current command in normal mode?

Tags: vimrc, normal-mode, command-history

Sometimes when entering a command in normal mode you may make a typo, for example if I intend to type `10dk`, I might accidentally start typing `19d`.

Since the command has not been completed/committed yet, is it possible to delete the incorrect keys using backspace, as such: `19d<backspace><backspace>0dk`, instead of having to hit escape and retry the command?

Side question: Is there a Vim term for the data structure which holds the current command before it's committed?

Comment: Probably, this can be asked as a feature in newer versions!

Comment: Related : http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/570/can-i-see-the-history-of-key-presses-in-normal-mode

Comment: AFAIK not possible - but, since these sequences are short, I'm not sure what gain would such a feature accomplish. When you have to retry the whole sequence, at least you are "forced" to repeat it until you make no such mistakes ;) (i.e. - repeating builds character! pun intended).

Comment: @VanLaser A Vimmer's worst nightmare is being "forced" to repeat something ;)

Also, I suck at typing and have a [blank keyboard](http://www.daskeyboard.com/daskeyboard-4-ultimate/) so it's not uncommon for me to mess up a command 256 times before getting it right.

Comment: I am afraid since no such feature can exist. Each key is taken literally as a part of an operation. In normal mode, backspace corresponds to `h`( moves backwards). So, 19`BS` might move 19characters backwards. Or, the command might become invalid if not expected key is pressed.

Comment: @DC_ So, your real problem is elsewhere :)

Comment: What could go wrong when a bad typist uses a blank keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do it and it is normal that there isn't: normal mode commands are generally pretty short and can be cancelled with <kbd>Esc</kbd> if you mess it.

A possible workaround would be to use the `:normal` command. It makes the process longer but for example if you type `:normal 10j` in the command line, Vim will execute `10j` as if you typed it in normal mode. (See [`:h :normal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal))

You could also add these lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <F4> :call NormalModeCommand()<CR>

function! NormalModeCommand()
    let command = input("Normal command: ")
    execute "normal " . command
endfunction
```

They create a mapping (here <kbd>F4</kbd> but use whatever you want) which will call the function `NormalModeCommand()`.

The function allows you to type a string in the command line and then execute the string you typed as a normal mode command. As you type the string in the command line you can correct it as every other command. Of course it is not ideal but once again Vim isn't meant to do that.