# Repeat not only last command

Tags: repeated-commands

The repeat command `.` is awesome. Is it possible to cycle through the last few commands, instead of only being able to repeat the last command? Something like yankring for repeat?

Comment: If you find yourself repeating a set of commands, record a macro and use it.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand Vim doesn’t have a way of repeating normal mode history use a while back, unless you write it out to a file:

https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/587/13848