# Is there a way to list out history of "normal mode command" for vim

Tags: command-history

We can get history for Ex commands and search with `q:` and `q/` or `q?`.

What about history for normal mode command (e.g., `s`, `yy`, `x`, `dw`, etc.)? Am I stuck with `:history`?

Comment: It would be useful to explain what you are trying to do with this history maybe there is a workaround for your use case. There isn't really an history for normal mode commands but you can record all you keypresses when invoking vim with `-w` [`:h -w`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#-w) and you can redo the last normal mode command with the dot command [`:h .`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#.)

Comment: Without more clarifications I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/570/1841)

Comment: The problem with using vim is that , accidental deletion of a large chunk of data happens under my nose.. and i was not aware of it. If i can map a button to check what command have i entered (when i got a feeling something might went wrong).. then i can prevent this kind of abhorable accidents.

Comment: I've never seen this kind of issue tbh so maybe there is something wrong with your workflow that you'd need to fix instead of relying on a command history. Also are you aware of [`:h :earlier`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/undo.txt.html#%3Aearlier) [`:h undo-redo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/undo.txt.html#undo-redo) and [`:h undo-tree`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/undo.txt.html#undo-tree) maybe that would be useful?

Comment: @statox To clarify: I wish there is a history command list that i might know what have occured when i got a hunch something has gone wrong (i might have accidentally pressed some command that might have messed out my data in anyway). Do you ever look back when you walk forward ? to look back to see if you missed something which you got a hunch..

Comment: The answer to your question is that such a thing doesn't exist in Vim/Neovim. Implementing it by yourself in vimscript will be not trivial and error prone, and implementing it in either of the projects will probably never be merged because it would introduce a lot of complexity for an added value which is not obvious. I think your best bet is to get used to undo/redo things and you'll see that it doesn't happen often that you do something without realizing.